# ExtendedLogService does not appear to start

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox, bndtools

I am attempting to run an Eclipse 3.x application using Equinox in Neon as initiated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031044/launching-an-eclipse-3-x-rcp-application-using-bndtools).

It appears that my remaining issue is that the **LogReaderService** appears to not be available, as the second line below in **org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog()** appears to throw a **NullPointerException**:

```
ExtendedLogReaderService logReader = logReaderTracker.getService();
logReader.addLogListener(result, result);
```

An implementation of this class can be found in **org.eclipse.osgi**, which I am launching the application with. For whatever reason, though, the service is null, which causes a number of plug-ins to throw exceptions when logging since many of the plug-ins rely on getting the Logging service from the Activator.

Since **org.eclipse.osgi** contains the implementation in its internals, I assumed that it would also register the service. That does not appear to be the case. I have also tried including **log4j** and **org.apache.felix.log** and neither appear to resolve this problem.

There must be something simple that is missing here to get the LogService to start? Here's the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (44).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 20 more

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
... 29 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog(InternalPlatform.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getLog(Platform.java:976)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.Policy.log(Policy.java:159)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.setCrashed(Workspace.java:2302)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreSnapshots(SaveManager.java:963)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:720)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1587)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2399)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
... 36 more
```

I also added

```
Require-Capability: osgi.service;filter:="(objectClass=org.osgi.service.log.LogService)";effective:=active
```

To one of the dependent **bnd** files. This did not appear to solve the problem.

---

Edit: Because the OSGI Framework is set to **org.eclipse.osgi** in the **bndrun** file, is that preventing the logging from getting initialized? I have also tried adding **org.apache.commons.logging** as well as **osgi.enroute.equinox.log.adapter** and I am still getting NPEs when anything attempts to log. The **org.eclipse.osgi** bundle is already considered running by the time the RCP plugins get activated... yet there is no **ExtendedLogReaderService**. Do I need to find a way to install Felix as the Core Runtime in order to make **org.eclipse.osgi** able to get started by the framework in order for the **ExtendedLogReaderServiceImpl** to get registered?

I have found numerous examples of how to listen for the LogService... I'm not seeing how to start the **ExtendedLogService**.

---

Edit 2: I am able to suppress the `LogService` nulls issue by registering dummy `ExtendedLogService` implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved (finally), revisiting this now that our build system is in place the solution was likely that `osgi.enterprise` was not a `Required-Bundle` which also caused caused our OSGI-JDBC services to not work properly when testing the deployed target platforms.

Additionally, our primary RCP plug-in (containing the `Application` class, etc.) did not have a `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` clause in the `*.bnd` files used to generate the `MANIFEST.MF` file which lead to some other problems.

Just in case anyone else runs into such problems.